# Проверка pull requests

Tags: git, github

Функционал гитхаба позволяет проверку pull requests запустить только в момент его создания?

Comment: "Только"? А в какие моменты вы **не** хотите её запускать?

Comment: а в какие моменты их можно запускать?

Comment: Вручную -- в любые. Меня интересует, что вы имели в виду под словом "только". Что вы хотели им исключить.

Comment: я знаю что мы можем делать проверку в момент открытия и в момент когда докидываем коммиты, а в какие еще моменты возможны?

Comment: Ну, имея широкие возможности настройки, можно [очень многие события отловить](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events). Но типичные CI запускаются так, чтобы, выборочно: (1) проверять кончики всех веток, (2) проверять потенциальные результаты мерджа всех pull request'ов в максимально свежем состоянии (поэтому при добавлении коммитов проверка запускается ещё раз). Всё это, вроде как, требует только одного события: `push`.

Comment: @D-side спасибо Вам!